# Visual studio 2015 update 2. Team Explorer not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I updated VS2015 to update 2.

Upgrade process finished fine, but after launch a lost access to Team explorer.

There is a bug with the following callstack instead.

```
    An exception was encountered while constructing the content of this frame.  This information is also logged in "C:\Users\volkov.a\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml".

Exception details:
System.InvalidOperationException: The window search was not yet setup for this search host.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowSearchHost.ThrowIfSearchNotSetup()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowSearchHost.set_HelpTopic(String value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.ToolWindowTeamExplorer.OnToolWindowCreated()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, UInt32 flags)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.FindToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, Boolean create, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Guid& toolWindowType, Int32 id)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsToolWindowFactory.CreateToolWindow(Guid& toolWindowType, UInt32 id)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

I tried repair and reinstall. No result.

Also I'm getting exception on launch:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

What else could I check?

Comment: @MrBeanzy Yes, See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll to Gac and that helped.

Comment: Did you have to restart after doing that?  Did you add it to "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\", which has three folders in it?  If so, which folder?

Comment: @Bryan I used gacutil to put assembly to gac. It detects correct folder automaticaly. You need to restart VS after that.

Answer (score 2):

I closed the Team Explorer Window then closed visual studio. I Opened visual studio again, went to view menu and click on Team Explorar it throwed a message box whit a exception, tried again open de Team Explorer Windows, and works.

Comment: I just closed and opened the Team Explorer Window and it started working again. Earlier also I remember doing the same but it didnt work!! But on trying again it worked. May be multiple restarts in between also helped. I'm not sure. Thanks anyways :)